# Creating zip file from multiple files

Tags: c#, zip

The code below is working fine in creating a zip file but the file created is having a folder IIS Deploy >>>WebService... then the text file and not just the text file.

How can I just add the text files to the zip file?

```
ZipFile z = ZipFile.Create("C:\\IIS Deploy\\WebServiceTest\\WebServiceTest\\Accident.zip");

//initialize the file so that it can accept updates
z.BeginUpdate();

//add the file to the zip file        
z.Add("C:\\IIS Deploy\\WebServiceTest\\WebServiceTest\\test1.txt");
z.Add("C:\\IIS Deploy\\WebServiceTest\\WebServiceTest\\test2.txt");
z.Add("C:\\IIS Deploy\\WebServiceTest\\WebServiceTest\\test3.txt");

//commit the update once we are done
z.CommitUpdate();
//close the file
z.Close();
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I think the solution might be to create the zipfile and add the contents without a fully-qualified path. There might also be an option to add files only (without regard to its containing path) on the Add method.

Comment: i tried that and got file error.. the path should be specified i guess

Comment: I think the solution offered in the answer from @codebased is a great path to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have everything within same folder then the easiest option is to use CreateFromDirectory class.

```
static void Main()
    {
    // Create a ZIP file from the directory "source".
    // ... The "source" folder is in the same directory as this program.
    // ... Use optimal compression.
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("source", "destination.zip",
        CompressionLevel.Optimal, false);

    // Extract the directory we just created.
    // ... Store the results in a new folder called "destination".
    // ... The new folder must not exist.
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("destination.zip", "destination");
    }
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/zipfile

Please note that it is applicable to .NET Framework 4.6 and 4.5

Comment: i am using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip